# Set default selected value of ComboBox in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My Form consist of a DataGridView and, inside of that, I have one Column as ComboBox.
The ComboBox is getting filled by the database query.

I wanted to display the default value of ComboBox in the DataGridView. I have loaded values in combo box but could not find a way to set a default value for that.

[image: Layout]

I have added values to a combo box with the following code on the click of the `btnLoadCombo` button:

```
private void btnLoadCombo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["InventoryManagerConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    //Filling ComboBoxes
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdGetRootCat = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblProductCategories", con);

    SqlDataReader sdaRootCat = cmdGetRootCat.ExecuteReader();
    comboBoxCatTest.Items.Clear();

    while (sdaRootCat.Read())
    {
        this.CatCombo.Items.Add(sdaRootCat["Cat_Name"]);
    }

    //Filling DataGridView
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Clear();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Cat_ID, Cat_Name FROM tblProductCategories", con);

    SqlDataReader sda = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dt.Load(sda);
    dataGridCatList.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();            
 }
```

I expect results as shown in image 2.

Comment: you can use `dataGridCatList.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = this.CatCombo.Items[yourDefaultValue]` this will set the default value of your first cell to the selected default value

Comment: No results... Sir please check my attached image to understand what i want. Thank you.

Comment: point out that this is only for the first cell

Comment: Yes, it is showing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridCatList.Rows)
{
    if(row.Cells[3].Value != null) //ignore last row which is empty
    {
        if( row.Cells[3].Value.Equals(1018) )
            row.Cells[0].Value = this.CatCombo.Items[0];
    }
    //...and so on
}
```

You are going through every row with the `foreach()` loop and compare the value of `Cat_ParentCat` with `row.Cells[3].Value.Equals(Cat_ParentCatValue)`. If a match is found, set the default value of the ComboBox with `row.Cells[0].Value = this.CatCombo.Items[yourDefaultValue];`